# Python - serial process, multthreading, muliprocess all taking same time to run in my local

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I was looking into [this article](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/introduction-to-parallel-and-concurrent-programming-in-python--cms-28612) and testing the same in my local :

```
import os
import time
import threading
import multiprocessing

NUM_WORKERS = 4

def only_sleep():
    print "PID: %s, Process Name: %s, Thread Name: %s" % (os.getpid(), multiprocessing.current_process(), threading.current_thread())
    time.sleep(2)

def crunch_numbers():
    print "PID: %s, Process Name: %s, Thread Name: %s" % (os.getpid(), multiprocessing.current_process(), threading.current_thread())
    x = 0
    while x < 10000000:
        x += 1

def main():

    start_time = time.time()
    for _ in range(NUM_WORKERS):
        only_sleep()
    end_time = time.time()

    print "serial time", end_time - start_time

    start_time = time.time()
    threads = [threading.Thread(target=only_sleep()) for _ in range(NUM_WORKERS)]
    [thread.start() for thread in threads]
    [thread.join() for thread in threads]
    end_time = time.time()

    print "Threads time = ", end_time - start_time

    start_time = time.time()
    processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=only_sleep()) for _ in range(NUM_WORKERS)]
    [process.start() for process in processes]
    [process.join() for process in processes]
    end_time = time.time()

    print "Process time = ", end_time - start_time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the output :

```
PID: 60230, Process Name: <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>, Thread Name: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735648224064)>
PID: 60230, Process Name: <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>, Thread Name: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735648224064)>
PID: 60230, Process Name: <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>, Thread Name: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735648224064)>
PID: 60230, Process Name: <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>, Thread Name: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735648224064)>
serial time 8.01504993439
PID: 60230, Process Name: <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>, Thread Name: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735648224064)>
PID: 60230, Process Name: <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>, Thread Name: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735648224064)>
PID: 60230, Process Name: <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>, Thread Name: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735648224064)>
PID: 60230, Process Name: <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>, Thread Name: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735648224064)>
Threads time =  8.01574707031
PID: 60230, Process Name: <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>, Thread Name: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735648224064)>
PID: 60230, Process Name: <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>, Thread Name: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735648224064)>
PID: 60230, Process Name: <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>, Thread Name: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735648224064)>
PID: 60230, Process Name: <_MainProcess(MainProcess, started)>, Thread Name: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 140735648224064)>
Process time =  8.0206348896
```

Below is my local system configuration :

[image]

All three serial, multithread, muliprocess are taking same time to run. Could someone help me understand why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reference a function you should not call it:

```
threading.Thread(target=only_sleep())
```

Should be:

```
threading.Thread(target=only_sleep)
```

And:

```
processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=only_sleep()) for _ in range(NUM_WORKERS)]
```

Should be:

```
processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=only_sleep) for _ in range(NUM_WORKERS)]
```

`()` is used to call functions.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I will check more on calling and referencing a function.

Comment: You simply reference them by name. Like anything else :)